# In ASP.NET MVC5, how can I hide the Action name when an a tag is generated in Razor using Url.Action?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

As the title says.

I have a route set up and working fine, which provides a default action when none is specified. I just want to hide the action from the URL because it's unnecessary clutter.

Setting the "ActionName" parameter as `null`, or `""`, will just result in the current page's action being substituted instead - which doesn't work.

I'm open to using `@Html.ActionLink()` if that will get me what I need.

My route definition is

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyBookRoute", 
    url: "Book/{id}", 
    defaults: new { controller = "Book", action = "Index" }
);
```

If all else fails, I suppose I can deal with writing out the hrefs manually, but this should not be a difficult thing for Razor to do.

Has anyone else come across this and knows what to do?

Comment: Show you route definitions

Comment: Hello Stephen, 

My route is as follows:

routes.MapRoute(
 name: "MyBookRoute",
 url: "Book/{id}",
 defaults: new { controller = "Book", action = "Index" }
);

Comment: So it you use `@Url.Action("Index", "Book")` then both the controller name and action name will be removed.

Comment: Definitely action and controller name will be removed if you use `@url.ACtion("Index", "Book") `

Comment: Yes I get this working now!! I don't know why it was shoving the action name in there before, but it's working now. Thank you very much. Is there a way for me to accept a comment as an answer? (It's my first time posting here)

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly (and update your question with the route)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on your route definition, then either

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Book", new { id = 1 })
```

or

```
@Html.ActionLink("Your link text", "Index", "Book", new { id = 1 }, null)
```

will remove the action name from the generated url.