# AbsoluteUri need to return correct path

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using method bellow in my **MVC view** I am getting URL like "`localhost:54871/Home/Index`" but I don't want "Index" on last. It should be only "`localhost:54871/Home`". How should I implement this?

```
@(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You can make his route and just given 
Redirect.toRoute("yourroute")

Hope so it can helpful

Comment: `Index` is your action method name, Are you trying to just show the `Controller` name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`  the url changes based on the user's current page.

If user visits `http://localhost:0000/Home/` then `AbsoluteUri` is  `http://localhost:0000/Home/`

If user visits `http://localhost:0000/Home/Index` then `AbsoluteUri` is  `http://localhost:0000/Home/Index`

In `MVC` url generation is based on the route definition defined in `RouteConfig.cs` file.

You can define route just for controller name, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729098/in-asp-net-mvc5-how-can-i-hide-the-action-name-when-an-a-tag-is-generated-in-ra) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8968689/routing-how-to-hide-action-name-in-url)

Also there is another solution as below:

```
@{
Uri uriAddress = new Uri(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);

string urlLeftPart = uriAddress.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);

string controllerName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.
Values["controller"].ToString();

string finalURL = urlLeftPart + "/" + controllerName;
}

<a href="@finalURL">Url Without Action Name</a>
```

References

[1.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14212069/2218697)

[2.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26415875/getting-controller-name-from-razor)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one.

For Example if the url with parameters are like below

```
http://localhost:61221/Websitetest/Default1.aspx?QueryString1=1&QueryString2=2
```

Then by using the below code you can get the results

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

will provide the output like below

**OUTPUT**

```
localhost
localhost:61221
61221
/Websitetest/Default1.aspx
/Websitetest
http://localhost:61221/Websitetest/Default1.aspx?QueryString1=1&QueryString1=2
/Websitetest/Default1.aspx?QueryString1=1&QueryString2=2
```

Comment: For some reason, while debugging my script AbsoluteUri returns only the path and query during runtime. However, in the immediate window, it shows the correct string. Is anyone else having this issue?